# Converting number into user generated input (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, input, wolfram-mathematica

im making a program that is used to write a function which takes array inputs x, y and integrates using the Midpoint Rule w/o using any form of built in integration. I currently have it working with temp int numbers (0 & 2), but i want to make it where its user generated inputs, not too many resources online for matlab to help me..

```
lower_limit = 0;
upper_limit = 2;

no_of_intervals = 100;

length_of_each_interval = (upper_limit - lower_limit)/no_of_intervals;



%Finding midpoints of the 100 intervals and storing in mid vector

temp=0
for i=1:100
   mid(i) = (temp + temp + length_of_each_interval)/2;
   temp = temp + length_of_each_interval; 
end

%Here midpoint of (a,b) is (a+b)/2 where a = temp and b = temp + length_of_each_interval


%Evaluating the integral

out=0
for i=1:100
   out = out + length_of_each_interval*(1/(mid(i)+4))
end

%In the above expression, the value of integrand (1/(x+4)) at mid points of intervals is
%given by (1/(mid(i)+4)

>>

out=
```

Comment: Did you look at the function `input`? https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/input.html

Comment: yes but also my code isnt printing anything so im working on a fix